# Organsing Html(text) appropriately

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have a document with all the html that I want to manipulate but its all over the place.
I can get it fairly tidy using

```
Elements paragraphs = document.select("p");
```

But its not the format that I want it in.
For example if its a table that I want to organise how do I just say take in the first set of elements eg(everything on a particular day monday) then everything on tuesday...

Im not sure how to select it correctly. As I want to put the txt into arraylists of class type.
In the html each set of info I want starts with td and ends with /td

So how do I select the first td then the second one then the third one etc.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Adding more information may help us help you. What does the markup look like? What do you mean by "take in the first set of elements"? What libraries are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, that I understand your porblem correctly and since I can't comment I am posting it as an answer.

You can select all of your td's and then get their childs

```
$('td').children('li').each(function(index, element) {
    and add them to your array here
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how they work please

Comment: It's jQuery selecotrs, first you select all td's, then for each of the td, you can find it's children, it can be any element or class, not just li, then you loop through them and form an array. Google these functions for more info.